# filesize reductions after setdar aspect ratio change

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I work with a lot of video files and, occasionally, I'll run across one that needs the aspect ratio adjusted. The problem is, I usually end up with a significantly smaller file size and lower bit rate.
I recently changed the dar from 16:9 to 5:4 for an old B&W film video. The sample I tested ended up with a bit rate about half the original and a filesize a little more than a third of the original.
I'm beginning to wonder if I'm losing data unnecessarily.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

My usual command line is as follows:
'''ffmpeg -i "video_sample02.mp4" -vf setdar=5:4 "video_sample02_dar54.mp4"'''

Comment: What's the video codec?

Comment: The codec is usually AVC x264.with  mp4 container/AAC audio.